# Expect all array elements to be of the same class

Tags: arrays, ruby, testing, rspec

I want to check that an array contains only objects of a specific class, let's say `Float`.

A working example at the moment:

```
it "tests array_to_test class of elements" do
  expect(array_to_test.count).to eq(2)
  expect(array_to_test[0]).to be_a(Float)
  expect(array_to_test[1]).to be_a(Float)
end
```

Is there a way to validate if the `array_to_test` contains only `Float` instances?

Sample non-working pseudocode:

```
it "tests array_to_test class of elements" do
  expect(array_to_test).to be_a(Array[Float])
end
```

Do not consider Ruby and Rspec version as a restriction.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try [`all`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/all-matcher):

```
expect(array_to_test).to all(be_a(Float))
```

Comment: Yes that's it! It seems I just couldn't find it in the Documentation...
Thank you for the fast reply!

Answer (score 1):

You could use ruby methods:

```
expect(array_to_test.map(&:class).uniq.length) to eq(1)
```

Or for better practice, implement a Helper using those methods:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :all_be_same_type do
  match do |thing|
    thing.map(&:class).uniq.length == 1
  end
end
```

and then use it this way:

```
expect(array_to_test) to all_be_same_type
```